# Display status bar notification from service in android

Tags: android, binding, service, notifications

Hi 
i've got a kind of a dumb problem. Im trying to display a notification from a service. When an activity starts i call the startService like so:

```
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),notif_service.class);
      startService(myIntent);
```

the service calculates something and should display the notification and then stop. the code is as follows:

```
    if (limit_time_value == 2 && start >= 6300000 && notif_past)
     {  

        notif_past=false;
        showNotification();
        stopSelf(); 

     }
```

There are two ways that this service can be stopped, ether from itself with stopSelf() or from a button in my activity with

```
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),notif_service.class);
      stopService(myIntent);
```

the problem is that even when i stop the service the notification is shown after the specified time passes. I tried to stop the setvice with Binding it and than calling onDestroy() in which I cancel the notification and again call stopSelf(). Again the notification is shown.

What am I doing wrong? Do I misunderstand how notifications or services work?

Comment: Try canceling your service and then going to Applications -> Running Services and see if your service is still running.  I have a hunch it is.

Comment: yea it is running, but shouldn't the service be stopped and not show the notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not indicate precisely where you are performing the work shown in your second code snippet above.

- If that work is being done in `onStart()` or `onStartCommand()`, that work is being performed on the main application thread, and therefore once it starts it blocks all other main application thread work, such as `stopService()` and `onDestroy()`.
- If that work is being done on a background thread you create, unless you are terminating that background thread, that thread will continue to completion, regardless of whether the service is destroyed. You will need to arrange to terminate the thread yourself.

Comment: yea it's in the main thread, it's just a service not a different thread. I though that the service will still be running if I exit the app as long I don't call something like stopSelf(). Should i use another thread? I didn't in the first place just to keep is simple

Comment: actually i just reread your second point and that is the problem, so i just terminate the thread in the service's onDestroy(). Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Call the instance of the NotificationManager class which you have called inside the `showNotification()` function.

For example, I have used:

```
NotificationManager nm=(NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nm.notify(1,builder.build());
```

If you have done something like this to create your notification, use the same instance to cancel it by calling `cancel()` function and passing the `notificationId` (in this case 1).

For example:

```
nm.cancel(1);
```

Here 1 denotes the `notificationID` which you have provided while creating it.