# How to add notification/ongoing event icon at particular position on status bar?

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar, notificationmanager

I want to put my ongoing event icon on status bar at 2nd position like Skype does on login.

Comment: u mean Creating a Custom Notification Layout ??

Comment: No. I want to put Status bar icon (like other application or battery icon on status bar) at position, say, 1st. So that it won't get hide/disappear even after new ongoing event icon appear on status bar. refer: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KkHW2.png screenshot for presence icon "P".

Comment: Notifications have both an explicit priority and an implicit one set by the system based on the time the notification is issued and other factors.  I'm sure if you bump the priority up to match that of Skype, Skype will no longer take precedence.  This is the same ordering the notifications appear in the drawer too.

Answer (score 1):

As the Notification Manager manages the notifications, this is not possible. The only way to get to the first position would be to have a Service and call [startForeground()](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) - but if another service already has done the same, your notification would be on the second position.

Apart from that there is no other way of influencing the position. If you create your notification first, you are on the first place. If another app creates the notification first, you are second.

Comment: No, it is not. This is probably because you have another service running already.

Comment: I created three applications which start service using  stratForeground() and trigger a notification with flag Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT. Installed and started them one by one, last/third application icon got hide from status bar. But at the end I started Skype and its icon was placed in front of all. My other two application icon got hide.

Answer (score 1):

So i went googling for this answer, and i found this question on the amazing StackOverflow. While `Notification.priority = Notification.PRIORITY_MIN` works for API 16 and higher, doing

`Notification.when = 0`

works wonderously for API < 16.

Answer (score 0):

http://grail.cba.csuohio.edu/~matos/notes/cis-493/lecture-notes/Android-Chapter23-Notifications.pdf

is a great document!

Check out the example:

> Produce a notification. Allow the user to click on the Notification
>   Panel and execute appropriate activity to attend the message.

Sorry to just post links. But, this will also be helpful, I believe:
[Display status bar notification from service in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834620/display-status-bar-notification-from-service-in-android)

Comment: Please read @Force's answer and my comment over it.....and thanks for your suggestions. :)

Answer (score 0):

When setting-up the notification, just set the .when field to Integer.MIN or Integer.MAX to respectively have the notification on the far left or far right.

Icons are sorted by this field on all versions of Android up-to ICS included.

On JB (4.1), you need to set the notification priority to get it on the left or right:

notification.priority = PRIORITY_MIN for the right side
notification.priority = PRIORITY_MAX for the left side

EDIT: On tablets, if you use Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE or startForeground, the icon will be positioned to the right and everything I tried to move it to the left didn't work (Tested on ICS).